# Flutter - How correctly pause camera when user moved to other (preview) screen?

Tags: android, flutter

I need to **pause** camera when I move to another screen on the navigator tree in order to save battery and performance.

I tried to `dispose()` cameraController, but flutter doesn't re-initialize the state when it returns from another screen (which is obvious, though).

My main code to work with a camera:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    availableCameras().then((cameras) {
      setState(() {
        _firstCamera = cameras.first;
        _controller = CameraController(_firstCamera, ResolutionPreset.high);

        _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          FutureBuilder<void>(
            future: _initializeControllerFuture,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {

              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return Stack(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Positioned.fill(
                      child: _getCameraPreview(context),
                    ),
                    ...                    
                  ],
                );
              } else {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            },
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: BottomAppBar(
              color: Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0),
              child: _getBottomAppBarRow(context),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _getCameraPreview(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final deviceRatio = size.width / size.height;
    return Transform.scale(
      scale: _controller.value.aspectRatio / deviceRatio,
      child: Center(
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
          child: CameraPreview(_controller),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Have a variable like `_cameraOff = false`. Show  `CameraPreview` when it is `true` and not when it is `false`. While navigating to another screen set it to `false`.

Comment: @10101010 and how can I correctly check the status of the state? Using AppLifecycleState paired with WidgetsBindingObserver?

Comment: You mean to ask how to check the value of the variable `_cameraOff `?

Comment: @10101010, No, no :) The status of the state. When I'm moving to another page it's easy to change _cameraOff value right after pushing a new item into `Navigator`, but what about the reverse case? How can I detect that user came back to the current state and turn back on a camera?

Comment: `Navigator.push` and many other methods of `Navigator` return a `Future` which is resolved when you pop back to that screen.

Comment: Ohh, so the `Navigator.push` is just an async method which is resolved when state poped back? It's a discovery for me! Thank you, I'll try to implement it in such way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196616/discussion-between-10101010-and-alectogeek).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a variable like _cameraOn = true. Show CameraPreview when it is true and not when it is false. While navigating to another screen set it to false

You could have the camera related functionality in a separate widget. So every time it is displayed it is initialized, and when it is not it's disposed.

A simple working example

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';

List<CameraDescription> cameras;

Future<void> main() async {
  cameras = await availableCameras();
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: CameraApp(),
  ));
}

class CameraApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CameraAppState createState() => _CameraAppState();
}

class _CameraAppState extends State<CameraApp> {
  bool _cameraOn = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: _cameraOn ? Camera() : Container(),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _cameraOn = false;
              });
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => Post())).then((res) {
                setState(() {
                  _cameraOn = true;
                });
              }).catchError((err) {
                print(err);
              });
            },
            child: Text("NEXT PAGE"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Camera extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CameraState createState() => _CameraState();
}

class _CameraState extends State<Camera> {
  CameraController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium);
    controller.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }

    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
      child: CameraPreview(controller),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class Post extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text("Post"),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This logic is not good enough! maybe we want to navigate to another page using another widget and could not set the state of the camera in this widget! Also setting the state in every move and then set back again is kind of ugly in practice.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the camera controller for an instance of the [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) package is defined as such:

```
List<CameraDescription> cameras = [];
controller = CameraController(
  cameras[0],
  ResolutionPreset.high,
  enableAudio: false,
);
```

This can be used to pause the camera:

```
controller.pausePreview();
```

This can be used to resume the camera:

```
controller.resumePreview();
```