# How should I pause the camera when navigating to new screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a barcode scanner functionality for a Flutter app. Most of the work has been done by the awesome guys at FlutterFire, and I'm using the example they have on their github, found here [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_ml_vision/example/lib/camera_preview_scanner.dart).

My question: what would be the best way to navigate away from this screen when a barcode is found, and return when a users presses back, without leaving the camera scanning or active in the background?

**Edit**

The problem lies in pausing both the `_camera.startImageStream`, and the `ScannerUtils.detect(` function.

I have tried calling the `_initializeCamera` function after awaiting the Navigator.push, but it seems that the initialize function is not done before the view is ready.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57071817/flutter-how-correctly-pause-camera-when-user-moved-to-other-preview-screen) It may be what you are looking for

Comment: This looks promising, thank you for your help. One more thing I am worried about, is the FirebaseVision image detector. This is a function that gets called onInit.

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed the issue by calling this function before navigating to the new screen:

```
void closeCameraAndStream() async {
  if (_camera.value.isStreamingImages) {
    await _camera.stopImageStream();
}
await _camera.dispose();

setState(() {
  _camera = null;
  _scanResults = null;
});
}
```

Also, I re-initialize the camera on returning to the screen, using this:

```
Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext routeContextcontext) => BarcodeResultScreen(barcodeValue)))
            .then((value) {
          _initializeCamera();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see they dispose of everything for you so if you don't use their widget anymore everything will be disposed properly.

Here is the code I'm talking about:

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    _camera.dispose().then((_) {
      _barcodeDetector.close();
      _faceDetector.close();
      _imageLabeler.close();
      _cloudImageLabeler.close();
      _recognizer.close();
      _cloudRecognizer.close();
    });

    _currentDetector = null;
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Indeed when an object is removed from the widget tree, it calls its method *dispose*. So programmers use this to close things which aren't useful anymore (such as the camera in your case).

Please check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html to learn more about dispose.

**Warning with Navigator.push**

If you use Navigator.push, flutter does not destroy the widget. You should use the deactivate method to do something when Navigator.push is called. There you could either call the dispose method
of their widget or hide it from your tree with a variable _isVIsible set to false.
Else just use Navigator.pushReplacement which will dispose the widget as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, I don't want to dispose the widget, because I don't believe that's how it should be done in Flutter. Maybe I am wrong though, and I would love to know!

Comment: So do you think I should call the dispose method in the widget itself?

Comment: You don't have to dispose it yourself but if you remove it from the widget tree it will call its dispose method (as explained in the link I gave you).

Comment: Ok so when I navigate to another screen, everything will stay initialised and scanning/running, right?

Comment: Flutter philosophy is to add/remove widget constantly from the widget tree, it is build to be efficient at doing so. I would advise you to watch this video where the Flutter team explain this better than I could : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=996ZgFRENMs

Comment: If you navigate to a screen where the CameraPreviewScanner is no longer in the widget tree, it won't be scanning/running anymore.

Comment: But if I remove it from the widget tree, I cannot press back or use navigator.pop()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216343/discussion-between-d-lucas-and-wekslie).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment.

I tested the Lulupointu's answer. It is working for me

the code has been customized as below

```
@override
void dispose() {
_camera.dispose().then((_) {
  _camera = null;
 });
  super.dispose();
}
```

Dont view the video until you cannot make it works. https://youtu.be/FozvYTtjZ3Y

Answer (score 0):

First, create a `dispose()` method at the top of your widget.

```
 @override
  void dispose() {
    controller!.stopCamera();
    controller!.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Then call it before navigating to the new screen:

```
    dispose(); // Don't forget to call this first.

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const AuthRouter(),
      ),
    );
```